# Combining output of two different select queries into a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using `oracle 10g` and just wanted to know  , if the below mentioned thing is possible or not.

I have to select two different values from two different tables and the output needs to be shown as a single row, with 2 columns.

Example scenario:-

```
Select col1 as A1  from table1 ;

Select clo2  as A2 from table2;
```

The output should be displayed as

```
A1. | A2

V1. |  V2
```

Where V1 , V2 are values from the above select queries.

Comment: See [**Oracle String Aggregation Techniques**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)

Comment: The link you have posted refers to retrieving different columns from same table. Here it is different columns from different tables . please correct me . if I am wrong in understanding your post

Comment: it is simple, `UNION ALL` the output and then apply the logic. Or, if you could `JOIN` the tables. Whatever it is, all you want is to aggregate the output.

Answer (score -1):

As @Lalit Kumar B says:

```
Select col1 as A1  from table1
UNION ALL
Select clo2  as A2 from table2
```

Remember you must have equal amount of columns selected from each table.